# Double click to reduce size of div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I was just wondering if there was a way of double clicking on a div and making the height reduce just by using CSS.

```
<div class="container"></div>
    <ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="#first" class="accordion-header">First</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" id="first">
        <p>Bonjour</p></div>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="#second" class="accordion-header">Second</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" id="second">
            <p>Hello</p></div>
        </li>


        <li>
        <a href="#third" class="accordion-header">Third</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" id="third">
            <p>No</p></div>
        </li>
```

You can find the code that I want to adjust in this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zec0o72g/).

Comment: No, with CSS a double click is not possible. Use JavaScript Instead.

Comment: Javascript only. However, if Javascript is not an option that you want, please do not put it as a tag.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti, difficult in CSS, but not impossible if some additional content can be added to each div.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Please don't actually use this. It's an interesting way to go about what you want, and a fun challenge for me, but Javascript is by far a more appropriate and reliable tool for the job. Unless you are burdened with a client who is demanding this functionality while completely against the use of JS, just slap some jQuery on it and call it a day.

So, <strike>I couldn't figure out how to do this with only CSS using the `ul` in your current markup, but if you're open to changing it a little bit, you can do this with CSS only.</strike> I'm dumb and just needed to plug the code below into the `ul` element. Here is an example:

HTML

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <span class="span" tabindex="0">
            <input type="text" value="&nbsp;" readonly="true" />
            <a href="#showme">Show</a>
        </span>
        <p id="showme" class="alert">Hidden Content</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font: 1em'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.accordion {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
span {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #bbb;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
span a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
span a:visited {
    color:#fff;
}
.alert {
    display: none;
    margin: 20px;
}
span {
    position: relative;
}
span a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
span a:hover, span a:active {
    z-index: 4;
}
span input {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 101%;
    height: 301%;
    z-index: 3;
}
span input:focus {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#showme:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yn13syuj/

Essentially, what this does is cover the `a` tag using some `z-index` trickery until you click it once. Then, once it's uncovered, you can use `:target` to change the `display` property of the hidden content.

Comment: this is a terrible idea to actually use in a real project, but +1 for clever code and for technically answering the question within the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Using only css you can't handle double click events, Use JavaScript and `.ondblclick` function to do this, here's a DEMO of your code:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-content");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

  divs[i].ondblclick = function() {
    if (this.offsetHeight > 50) {
      this.style.height = this.offsetHeight - 20 + "px";
    }
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 1em'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.accordion-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #bbb;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.accordion-content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 400ms ease;
  transition: height 400ms ease;
}
.accordion-content p {
  margin: 20px;
}
.accordion-content:target {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<ul class="accordion">
  <li> <a href="#first" class="accordion-header">First</a>

    <div class="accordion-content" id="first">
      <p>Bonjour</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#second" class="accordion-header">Second</a>

    <div class="accordion-content" id="second">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#third" class="accordion-header">Third</a>

    <div class="accordion-content" id="third">
      <p>No</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It keeps decreasing the height until it reachs `50 px`, you can change it to fit your needs.

And here's your **[updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zec0o72g/1/)**.

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable in CSS only, if you can add the following HTML immediately after each `<div class="accordion-content">`:

```
<a href="#"></a><input>
```

Then add these styles:

```
.accordion-content {
  position: relative;
}

.accordion-content a, .accordion-content input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.accordion-content input:focus {
  z-index: -1;
}

.accordion-content a:focus {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mjLv275u/3)